# How to configure Gnome 3 through a configuration file?

Tags: gnome, configuration, gtkrc

Before, one could configure certain options in Gnome 2.x through the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file. With Gnome 3, one would assume that `~/.gtkrc-3.0` works but it doesn't.

Comment: which OS version you are using

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 amd64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**gtk 3.0 / Gnome 3 settings** can be overwritten using `~/.config/gtk-3.0/`, with files `gtk.css` and `settings.ini`. They do not exist initially so you have to create the directory and files manually. If you create `settings.ini` add at least a line containing `[Settings]` in it, otherwise apps will complain about it missing.

See `/usr/share/theme/[theme_name]/gtk-3.0/*.css` files for hints of what you can change.

Most likely you will want to use `gtk.css` to override visual settings from the desktop theme with your own preferences. I usually don't edit `gtk.css` itself but rather append a line saying `@import url("gtk-mine.css");` and put my stuff in `gtk-mine.css`. This way, in case someone ever overwrites that file, I only lose the `@import` line, not all my personal rules.

Here's a short example of how to override some scrollbar attributes:

**~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk-css:**

```
@import url("gtk-mine.css");
```

**~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk-mine.css:**

```
* {
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 18;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 0;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 0;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-secondary-forward-stepper: 0;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-secondary-backward-stepper: 0;
  -GtkScrollbar-min-slider-length: 30;
}
.scrollbar.slider.vertical,
.scrollbar.button.vertical {
  border-radius: 4;
}
```

Comment: Seeing your post, I think its great that Gnome 3 uses CSS for style. Thanks for your answer! I initially wondered about this because I wanted to change icon sizes, but I guess there is some option somewhere on the CSS files for doing that.

Comment: Thanks, helpful. btw, /usr/share/theme/ should be /usr/share/themes/